# Possível atitude de desrespeito com usuário novo?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, respostas

Talvez está pergunta seja desnecessária aqui no meta, mas eu me sinto culpado quando não tenho certeza do que fiz, portanto irei perguntar.

**Questão:** [include, require dentro de funções métodos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/60314/3635)

Eu fiz está pergunta um usuário novo colocou uma [**resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/60329/3635) que ao meu ver nem de longe responde ao que foi perguntado, tudo bem até este ponto (é normal acontece), o problema é que o usuário quis justificar a resposta dele usando apenas um trecho da minha pergunta:

> Especifique melhor a sua pergunta, pois você deixou claro questão da utilização do require na versão 5.3, e o comando require por natureza pode ser utilizado em qualquer parte do código.

Então talvez eu tenha respondido de modo inapropriado (eu realmente não sei rs):

> a pergunta está bem especificada :)

Será que eu fui tão duro assim com ele? Como proceder melhor quando o usuário da uma resposta que você discorda?

Ao meu ver fiz várias "ofertas de paz".

Comment: Não vi nenhum desrespeito de sua parte, apenas da parte dele. No máximo, no máximo, uma reação exagerada quando ele diz que achou a pergunta 'um tanto "amadora"', não vi necessidade de se colocar na defensiva. É um porre quando aparece um novato, que não nos conhece, e devido à sua própria ignorância pensa que *nós* é que somos os ignorantes... Mas [quando isso acontece comigo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21026689#21026689) eu só dou risada! De todo modo, eu li dessa forma: "quando vi a pergunta não entendi, estranhei, achei que fosse uma coisa boba, mas vejo que não é".

Comment: Seu maior erro foi levar adiante uma conversa que poderia ter terminado [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60314/include-require-dentro-de-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-m%c3%a9todos#comment124358_60329). Nesse ponto fica claro que havia um entendimento errado da pergunta, o que é comum, independentemente de quanto a gente acha que nosso texto é claro. Dali pra frente a conversa foi você insistindo que tinha sido claro, e ele não se importando mais com isso. Você tentou ser gentil e solícito, mas esticou a conversa além da paciência dele. É a receita pra dar errado :)

Comment: Nessas horas o melhor é ignorar e não alimentar esse tipo de discussão. Você fez sua parte, recebeu o feedback dele, explicou e ele não entendeu. Infelizmente tem gente que não sabe conviver em comunidade e acaba criando um conflito por causa de ego.

Comment: Concordo com o @bfavaretto, era pra ter ignorado naquele ponto, deu pra ver que ia tomar um rumo estranho. No primeiro *assunto encerrado* já dava pra ver que tinha descambado. Quando há muita imposição, é melhor deixar de lado.

Comment: É aquela história: é impossível explicar quando o outro está decidido a não entender.

Comment: Não vi problema algum na sua pergunta. Para mim está bem clara.

Comment: Apesar de eu ter achado o tal usuário bastante exagerado sem necessidade, andei lendo como outros usuários costumam lidar com "Respostas erradas" ou incompletas e percebi realmente que dá para fazer um comentário rápido e não parecer grosseiro. Isto não quer dizer que fui mal-educado, pois notei que muitos usuários comentam de forma semelhante a minha e mesmo assim nunca vi muitos atritos por causa disto.

Comment: Essa vai servir pra eu aprender a não ser tão legal http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3733/existe-alguma-parte-da-moderação-do-site-referente-a-ética-não-sei-se-seria-a-m?cb=1#comment9628_3737 ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Já limpei os comentários lá, e parece hora de dar o caso por encerrado. Ao meu ver, houve ali um duplo ruído na comunicação: primeiro, o autor da resposta entendeu mal a pergunta. Depois, vocês dois não conseguiram se entender nos comentários e a coisa descambou. Parece que ambos se sentiram ofendidos, e de fato ofenderam um ao outro, de maneiras diferentes.

Como eu disse no comentário acima, a conversa poderia ter terminado bem antes. Havia um mal-entendido? Sim. Ele foi esclarecido? Sim. É isso que importa, e naquela altura os comentários já haviam cumprido o seu papel. Mesmo que restasse entre os interlocutores algum mal-estar, isso faz parte da vida, e não teria maiores consequências para nenhum dos dois. Mas quando cada um cisma que precisa convencer o outro de que está certo, e ele é quem está errado, os ânimos tendem a se acirrar. Já vi isso acontecer diversas vezes no site, e aconselho, a ambos: basta registrar suas opiniões e eventuais discordâncias, e partir pra outra.

Comment: Eu sinceramente não quis ofendê-lo, eu queria dar chance dele refazer a resposta, mas realmente eu nunca sou de ficar explicando e ao tentar fazê-lo só ocasionou problema rs